# How to make the JIT extend stack variables to the end of scope (GC is too quick)

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, jit

We're dealing with the GC being too quick in a .Net program. 
Because we use a class with native resources and we do not call GC.KeepAlive(), the GC collects the object before the Native access ends. As a result the program crashes.
We have exactly the problem as described here:

[Does the .NET garbage collector perform predictive analysis of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161119/does-the-net-garbage-collector-perform-predictive-analysis-of-code)

Like so:

```
{  var img = new ImageWithNativePtr();
   IntPtr p = img.GetData();
   // DANGER!
   ProcessData(p);
}
```

The point is: The JIT generates information that shows the GC that img is not used at the point when GetData() runs. If a GC-Thread comes at the right time, it collects img and the program crashes. One can solve this by appending GC.KeepAlive(img);
Unfortunately there is already too much code written (at too many places) to rectify the issue easily.

Therefore: Is there for example an Attribute (i.e. for ImageWithNativePtr) to make the JIT behave like in a Debug build? In a Debug build, the variable img will remain valid until the end of the scope ( } ), while in Release it looses validity at the comment DANGER.

Comment: I believe `GC.KeepAlive` is your only option here.

Comment: Doesn't your unmanaged resource need some kind of disposing?

Comment: Code that depends on a stupid implementation is broken.

Comment: This is why the SafeHandle class exists.  The band-aid you are looking for has to be ripped off quickly.  Solve this the right way.

Comment: The Dispose / Finalizer of the Image object releases the memroy - therefore the app crashes. It wasn't my design - I just have to fix it. Unfortunately there are pitfalls like shared objects etc.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to control jitter's behavior based on what types a method references. You might be able to attribute the method itself, but that won't fill your order. This being so, you should bite the bullet and rewrite the code. `GC.KeepAlive` is one option. Another is to make `GetData` return a safe handle which will contain a reference to the object, and have `ProcessData` accept the handle instead of `IntPtr` — that's good practice anyway. GC will then keep the safe handle around until the method returns. If most of your code has `var` instead of `IntPtr` as in your code fragment, you might even get away without modifying each method.

Comment: The most expressive syntax (instead of KeepAlive) if a safe handle / dedicated object is not possible would be to make `ImageWithNativePtr` implement `IDisposable` and wrap the code in `using (var img = new ImageWithNativePtr()) { ... }`

Comment: Indeed, but that would require more code changes. BTW the whole `ImageWithNativePtr` could derive from `SafeHandle`.

Comment: The IDisposeable strategy was of course thought thru - however that requires heaps of code changes. The only thing to hold on yet is still the scoping of the instructions. But as we know the GC does a quicker job.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. (Requires work, more correct) - Implement `IDisposable` on your `ImageWithNativePtr` class as it compiles down to `try { ... } finally { object.Dispose() }`, which will keep the object alive provided you update your code with `using`s. You can ease the pain of doing this by installing something like CodeRush (even the free [Xpress](http://devexpress.com/crx) supports this) - which supports creating `using` blocks.
2. (Easier, not correct, more complicated build) - Use [Post Sharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) or Mono.Cecil and create your own attribute. Typically this attribute would cause GC.KeepAlive() to be inserted into these methods.

The CLR has nothing built in for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can emulate what you want with a container that implements IDispose, and a using statement. The using statement allows for defining the scope and you can place anything you want in it that needs to be alive over that scope. This can be a helpful mechanism if you have no control over the implementation of ImageWithNativePtr.

The container of things to dispose is a useful idiom. Particularly when you really should be disposing of something ... which is probably the case with an image.

```
using(var keepAliveContainer = new KeepAliveContainer())
{
  var img = new ImageWithNativePtr();
  keepAliveContainer.Add(img);
  IntPtr p = img.GetData();
  ProcessData(p);
  // anything added to the container is still referenced here.
}
```

Comment: good idea - though I would put the image as a contructor parameter.